# Что указать в параметре responseType метода exchange RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Пытаюсь сформировать запрос

```
private final RestTemplate httpClient;
ResponseEntity<DataEntity<User>> response =
    httpClient.exchange(Url,
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    httpEntity,
    User.class);
```

И получаю ошибку

```
Required type:ResponseEntity<DataEntity<User>>
Provided:ResponseEntity<User>
```

Что мне надо указать в этом параметре?

```
DataEntity - это класс обертка
public class DataEntity<T>{
    private T data;
}
```

Что мне надо указать вместо User.class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `ParameterizedTypeReference`
Это специальный вспомогательный класс в Spring Framework, предназначенный для передачи ссылок на обобщения/параметризируемые классы

```java
new ParameterizedTypeReference<DataEntity<User>>() {}
```

**В итоге:**

```java
private final RestTemplate httpClient;
ResponseEntity<DataEntity<User>> response =
    httpClient.exchange(Url,
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    httpEntity,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<DataEntity<User>>() {}
);
```